# Creating mp4 file with Media Foundation fails on certain machines

Tags: windows-store-apps, mp4, ms-media-foundation

I have a Windows Store app in which I use Media Foundation to create mp4 files. I use the function MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL to create the file and the function IMFSinkWriter.WriteSample to write audio and video data to the file. This all works fine on my DELL laptop, my Surface tablet. So these mp4 files play well on all machines. When the app runs on an ASUS ME400C tablet, it creates an mp4 file, but the file can not be played back on that machine or on any other machine. So the app is on all machines the same (downloaded from the store), but the encoding is different.

If I open the file in TopoEdit tool, I get the following error: Failed to create source node. The byte stream type of the given URL is unsupported.

How to find out what the problem is with the mp4 file created by the Asus machine? Are there tools that can help me analyzing that file?

Just in case someone is interested. I have here a mp4 created with an Asus machine

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A6F31F60861DD2C!449&authkey=!AJVXFclI4BoJs0o

and a mp4 created with my Dell laptop here

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A6F31F60861DD2C!450&authkey=!AKtrfkDprZyJJI0

Regards

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

Use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) or [QuickTime](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL837) to check the format of the file

Asus.mp4 file is corrupted one. This is file is not opening in VLC, Media Player and Quick Time.If you right click the file and check the **Properties->Details** you will find Video and Audio section empty.While creating the file some where your code is failing or file properties is not properly set. It is able to create the file but certain properties is missing.Use **MFTrace** to find that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this will give me a good starting point!